# PHP pick tweets code

Tags: php, twitter, rss

I have a php code that fetches my latest tweet and displays it on my website. It works great but I would like to know if I could do this but maybe fetching my 5 last tweets instead of only the latest. This is my code for twitter.php:

```
function returnTweet()
{

   $username = "username";
   $prefix = "<div><big><i><a href=\"http://twitter.com/$username\">@$username</a> ";
   $suffix = "</i></big></div>";

   $feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=5";
   $twitterFeed = file_get_contents($feed);

   $tweet = parse_feed($twitterFeed);
   return $prefix.$tweet.$suffix;
} 


function parse_feed($feed)
{
    $stepOne = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);
    $stepTwo = explode("</content>", $stepOne[1]);
    $tweet = $stepTwo[0];
    $tweet = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $tweet);
    $tweet = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $tweet);
    return $tweet;
}
```

And i display it in my php page like this:

```
include "twitter.php";              
echo "".returnTweet();
```

Would appreciate any help in this! 
Regards from Paparappa

Comment: may I ask for the sense of `echo "".` ?

Comment: http://www.acornartwork.com/blog/2010/04/12/tutorial-twitter-rss-feed-parser-in-pure-php/ <- this might be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're much better off using an XML-parser for this (for example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

(not sure about the structure of twitter-atoms, so $xml->tweet[$i] is probably something else..)

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($twitterFeed);
$tweets = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $tweets[] = $xml->tweet[$i];
}
```